# Force https for all domains (I don't understand)

Tags: .htaccess

The following seems to work well for forcing https. I put this in a directory that is a wildcard subdomain.

examples:
abc.phppointofsale.com, def.phppointofsale.com...etc

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Does this mean if https is NOT on, then match anything and redirect to SERVER_NAME + REQUEST_URI.

Where is SERVER_NAME defined? could I use HTTP_HOST? What is the difference?

Also, why do you need a matching pattern in the rewrite rule when there already is a RewriteCondition?

Could someone point me to a good tutorial on Rewriting?

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Look at the apache website for the tutorial. "It's voodoo, but its damn cool voodoo". The rewriting process is quite complex, different stages, guessing if its a file path or an url path etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteCond does not do any redirection. It's only a sort of condition for the RewriteRule, an "if statement" if you will.

You can use HTTP_HOST just as well. SERVER_NAME will be the "official" name on the virtual host in the Apache configuration, while HTTP_HOST will be the hostname given by the user's browser.

Comment: If I have *.phppointofsale.com, will the vhost resolve to the subdomain? (It appears to)